# Unable to order date in column-wise in php

Tags: php, database

I was trying to automate the roll call system in my college and came across this problem,
I'm trying to print the dates of the register and instead of getting normal ordering, i'm getting this sort of output.

[image: This is the output i'm getting in the browser]

Here is the code i used in php,

```
for ( $i = 0 ; $i < count ( $attendance ) ; $i++ )<br>
     $data.="<th rowspan='2'>".$attendance[$i]['date']."</th>";
```

Comment: Please post your query - the issue is probably with your SQL, not the PHP code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you sorting the dates and how are they stored?

Looks like it's ordering by the first digit, not seeing the date as a whole.

Comment: It seems that i'm storing the date values as string, is there anyway so that i can order this properly without editing the table(editing the table is causing many more problems).

Comment: Maybe try strtotime(). You'll have to order in php then though which isn't preferable to doing it in the SQL.